# Finding Points at Which Vertical Distance Between 2 Lines = X

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two lines, and would like to find the pair of points (which lie on either line) which are to the left of the point at which the lines intersect, where the vertical distance between the two lines is exactly equal to 2 units. How can I do this?

$B_L = -\frac{2}{7}x + 3$

$R_L = \frac{3}{140}x + \frac{17}{20}$

[image]

Comment: You just need to solve $$B_L-R_L=2$$for the associated $x$ coordinate.

Comment: @PeterForeman would that be a simultaneous equation?

Comment: No it's just a single linear equation.

Comment: @PeterForeman Ah yes I see now. Thanks for your help!